# CSS Before selector dont show on server

Tags: html, css

i have a problem, question about css `:before` selector. On my local page all selectors working good, show a Font Awsome icon.

```
.contact_page ul li a.help:before {
content: "\f1cd";
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: inherit;
color: #F57C00;
font-size: 18px;
padding-right: 0.5em;
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
left: -3px;
padding-left: 3px;
}
```

But on server is not loading in DOM. Also this element i use on page footer and there is working. **Mystery**.

Comment: Please provide link on server

Comment: So the CSS works when you view it on your local machine, but when you put the CSS on the server and view it there (through the same browser, but a different address), something doesn't work? I can only think that you have some difference between the webpage (HTML, CSS) on your local machine and your server. Are you sure they're the same?

Comment: It is the same code, html, css, puting via GIT. Interesting is that on footer elements the same css before code is working.

Comment: You need to provide complete code

Answer (score 0):

- Check your import-statements.
  Try inserting this into your `head`-tag:

  ```
  <link href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  ```
- If there isn't a `@font-face` declaration like this:

  ```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  ```

  then you mustn't use `font-family: FontAwesome;`.